# Symfony 5: How can I make users choose which database to connect to, before logging in?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I have a symfony 5 project, and I would like to duplicate my database on which there will have differents datas from the default one (for another site). and I'd like to allow users to choose which database they want to connect to before logging in.
I tried to do those solutions describe in this posts :
[Is there a better way to achieve multiple connection to database in Symfony 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749502/is-there-a-better-way-to-achieve-multiple-connection-to-database-in-symfony-6)
[Symfony 3 connection to multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313830/symfony-3-connection-to-multiple-databases)

The idea is before login , the user choose which site he want to access.

My factory :

```
class EntityManagerFactory {

    private $config_db_group;

    public function __construct(string $config_db_group) {
        $this->config_db_group = $config_db_group;
    }

    public function createManager($idDb) {

        $isDevMode = false;
      
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . "/src"), $isDevMode);
        

        //$connectionConfig = $this->getConfigDb($idDb);

        $dbParams = [
            'url' => $idDb,
        ];
        return EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
    }

    
}
```

My doctine.yaml :

```
doctrine.yaml:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
                schema_filter: ~^(?!rememberme_token)~
                charset: utf8mb4
            SITE70:
                url: '%env(resolve:SITE70_DATABASE_URL)%'
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
                schema_filter: ~^(?!rememberme_token)~
                charset: utf8mb4
    orm:
        #default_entity_manager: default        
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            SITE70:
                connection: SITE70
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    SITE70:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
```

My service

```
App\Factory\EntityManagerFactory:
        arguments:
            $config_db_group: '%kernel.project_dir%\config\packages\doctrine.yaml'

    App\Factory\EntityManager:
        factory: ['@App\Factory\EntityManagerFactory', 'getManager']
```

and my controller :

```
class DataBaseConnectionController extends AbstractController
{    
    
    private $factory;
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig , EntityManagerFactory $factory ) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/Site", name="app_login_database_connection")
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response {
        
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('database', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Site1' => '1',
                    'Site2' => '2',
                ]
            ])
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->factory->createManager('mysql://root:root@localhost/CFA70',);
            
           /* if ($Site1 = 1) {
                $entityManager = $this->factory->createManager('default');
                dd($entityManager);
            }else{
                $entityManager = $this->factory->createManager('Site70');
                dd($entityManager);
            }           */
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }       
        
        return $this->render('security/database.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }

}
```

the dump of $entityManager shows that in the config there is the correct url with the chosen database but it only connects to the default database,

I admit that I am not an expert, I try to learn on my own by applying in some projects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i used multiple entitymanagers before and this should work as following. Import the ManagerRegistry from `use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;`. Then inject this in your index() function like `index(Request$request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine)`. Now you can create your entityManager - default: `$entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();` and site70: `$entityManager = $doctrine->getManager('SITE70');`

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Richter Thank you for your comment.
I expressed myself badly, I have two identical databases, I would like the user before connecting to have the choice between the two databases, and this choice remains permanent until disconnection, for the database default data all the controller and database are created, I don't want to duplicate my code for SITE70, I don't know if possible.
for example ; to show show all users :

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="users_index", methods="GET|POST")
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function index(Request $request,  PaginatorInterface $paginator): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findAll();

        $users = $paginator->paginate(
            $user, // Requête contenant les données à paginer
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1), // Numéro de la page en cours, passé dans l'URL, 1 si aucune page
            20 // Nombre de résultats par page
        );

        return $this->render('admin/users/index.html.twig', [
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

if i choose my default database before loggin i will have all users in default database, if Site70 i'll have only those in SITE70